# trigger AWS Lambda function via MS teams

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, microsoft-teams

Is there a way we can trigger AWS Lambda function from Microsoft Teams. what I wanted to achieve is that stakeholders be able to approve merge requests from MS teams or maybe give an approval on Production rollout.

Is this connection possible at all?

Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is definitely possible, but there are a bunch of things you need to do to get a full working solution, so it's hard to give it all in one answer here. Here are some guidelines to get started though:

1. You need a something for the user to actually "Approve", and way to do this. A common approach is to send a ["Card"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/what-are-cards) to Teams, which can have an "Approve" button. There are a few different kinds of cards, and different ways to send them to Teams, including a Bot, Flow/PowerAutomate (which uses it's own Bot behind the scenes) and incoming Webhooks.
2. When the user clicks the "Approve" (or "Reject") buttons, you need a way to handle the action (to link the button click to AWS).

If you've built Bots before, this might be the easiest option. If you want to use Flow/Power Automate, that's another option (see [here](https://poszytek.eu/en/microsoft-en/office-365-en/powerautomate-en/register-response-from-custom-adaptive-cards-sent-from-power-automate-to-teams/) for more information about important changes due "this quarter" - I'm not sure if they're released yet). If you've not used any of these, your best bet might be:

1. Configure an [Incoming Webhook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/add-incoming-webhook)
2. Send a [Connector Card](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/connectors-using) with a "Post" button
3. Set the POST url to be your AWS Lambda

Comment: I made this to work somewhat with the hint that you gave above!!Appreciate your help.

Comment: sure thing, glad to help